# How to filter array with only purchases made by user

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a function that will return the sum of all the purchases the user made.

```
export async function getBalance(asd) {
  const response = await api.get("/compras")
  const { data } = response

  // customerSuccess.filter(({ id }) => !customerSuccessAway.includes(id))

  const userPurchases = data.map((item) => item.userId.includes(asd))
  // const userPurchases = data.filter(({ userId }) => !asd.includes(userId))
  console.log(userPurchases)
}
```

The getBalance(id) receives the ID of the user that is logged in. Its type is number, so I cannot use the filter method to filter the array that will be returned in the api call.

The response of the api is and array of objects that contains the 'value' and the 'userId'. What I want is to compare the ID that the function receives and check if there is any purchase made by this id (compare ID with userID) and return the sum of the 'value' of its purchases. Does anyone have an idea on how to do that? I thought about using map or reduce, but couldn't make a solution =(

api response:
[image: api response]

Comment: Please provide data as text, not as a picture of text. You can copy from the raw response, or use `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2))` to produce a nicely formatted presentation of the data.

Comment: it's bad to use `includes` to check matching ids. if you have an item with id `fas123` and check against `f`, then you will have a match. you need to check exactly the match

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter the purchases and then use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to compute the sum of the purchase values.

```js
const userPurchases = data
  .filter((purchase) => purchase.userId === asd)
  .reduce((sum, purchase) => sum + purchase.value, 0)
```

And a terse version (although less readable than the first):

```js
const userPurchases = data.reduce(
  (sum, purchase) => (purchase.userId === asd ? sum + purchase.value : sum),
  0
)
```

Comment: fwiw, you could use reduce only to avoid double loops, using the condition inside the reduce

Comment: @buzatto Yeah. I was going for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
customerSuccess.filter((item) => item.userId === asd
```

Comment: Answers consisting of (incomplete) code and words like "Try this" are generally not upvoted as often as those that provide references and explain how the code solves the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// get all the items from the user with the specific id
const filtered = data.filter((item) => item.userId === asd)
// sum all the values for user with the specific id
const totalValue = filtered.reduce((a, b)=>{return a + b.value} ,0)
console.log(totalValue) 
``
```